# How to pass one more parameter in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("SetDisplaySettings", "DisplaySettings")',
    data:$('#Form1').serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $('#chkIsSystemDefault').prop('checked', false);
        if(result=="2"){
           showAlertBox("Display Settings updated.");   
        }
    }
});
```

I need to pass one more parameter, `CountryId`. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe something like `data: { Data: $('#Form1').serialize(), countryId: CountryId },`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like below in your current code (will add data into serialize form itself):-

```
data:$('#Form1').serialize()+ '&CountryId=' +  CountryId,
```

Or you can use [`serializeArray` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'CountryId', value:  CountryId});
```

Comment: @DevTry  glad to help you buddy :):)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an `object` as your data like so :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SetDisplaySettings", "DisplaySettings")',
        data:{
            form : $('#Form1').serialize(),
            other : ...
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#chkIsSystemDefault').prop('checked', false);
            if(result=="2")
            {
                showAlertBox("Display Settings updated.");   
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code to help you understand how can you pass multiple parameters in an AJAX request:

```
var paramsToSend = {};
paramsToSend['form'] = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
paramsToSend['CountryId'] = CountryId;

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {params:JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)},
    ...
});
```

In your server-side, may be PHP, you can:

```
$parameters = json_decode($_POST['params']);
```

To convert them to array and have that array in $_POST, you can:

```
$_POST = (array) $parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(...).serialize()` you can use the `FormData` object: [FormData on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).
Do something like that:

```
var data = new FormData( document.getElementById("#myForm") );
data.append( "CountryId", countryIdValue );
//... in AJAX block:
data: data,
//...
```